# How to apply an Effect (ie: TGaussianBlurEffect) to a single texture?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I draw several textures on my canvas and on one of them i would like to apply a TGaussianBlurEffect. Problem is that TGaussianBlurEffect will apply to all the container in with it is placed (so all the canvas) where me i want to apply it only to one texture.

i found this function in delphi

```
procedure TFilterEffect.ProcessTexture(const Visual: TTexture; const Context: TContext3D);
var
  Ver: TVertexBuffer;
  Ind: TIndexBuffer;
  Mat: TTextureMaterial;
begin
  if Assigned(FFilter) then
  begin
    FFilter.ValuesAsTexture['Input'] := Visual;
    FFilter.ApplyWithoutCopytoOutput;
    if Assigned(Context) then
      if Context.BeginScene then
      try
        Ver := TVertexBuffer.Create([TVertexFormat.Vertex, TVertexFormat.TexCoord0], 4);
        Ver.Vertices[0] := Point3D(Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.X,
          Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.Y, 0);
        Ver.TexCoord0[0] := PointF(0.0, 0.0);
        Ver.Vertices[1] := Point3D(Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.X + Visual.Width,
          Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.Y, 0);
        Ver.TexCoord0[1] := PointF(Visual.Width / TFilterManager.FilterTexture.Width, 0.0);
        Ver.Vertices[2] := Point3D(Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.X + Visual.Width,
          Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.Y + Visual.Height, 0);
        Ver.TexCoord0[2] := PointF(Visual.Width / TFilterManager.FilterTexture.Width,
          Visual.Height / TFilterManager.FilterTexture.Height);
        Ver.Vertices[3] := Point3D(Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.X,
          Context.PixelToPixelPolygonOffset.Y + Visual.Height, 0);
        Ver.TexCoord0[3] := PointF(0.0, Visual.Height / TFilterManager.FilterTexture.Height);
        Ind := TIndexBuffer.Create(6);
        Ind[0] := 0;
        Ind[1] := 1;
        Ind[2] := 3;
        Ind[3] := 3;
        Ind[4] := 1;
        Ind[5] := 2;
        Mat := TTextureMaterial.Create;
        Mat.Texture := TFilterManager.FilterTexture;
        Context.Clear(0);
        Context.SetContextState(TContextState.cs2DScene);
        Context.SetContextState(TContextState.csZWriteOff);
        Context.SetContextState(TContextState.csZTestOff);
        Context.SetMatrix(TMatrix3D.Identity);
        Context.DrawTriangles(Ver, Ind, Mat, 1);
        Mat.Free;
        Ind.Free;
        Ver.Free;
      finally
        Context.EndScene;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

but i don't understand it's purpose and how to use it :(

Comment: You will have to GaussianBlur your texture and save the resulting image before you put it on the canvas with the other textures.

Comment: yea, but how to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried this:
http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/how-to-save-an-image-with-effec/1987968